# searching for all occurrences of a string in algolia

Tags: ios, search, algolia

In Algolia, currently when I search for say " amazon books" in my database that has entries of

- amazon bag
- books from amazon
- amazon books
- books from google books

I get "amazon books" as the result. What I am looking for is for all entries with "amazon" OR "books" to be shown in the result. How would I perform this search ?

Or do I have to just send multiple queries from my iOS app - one for amazon and one for swift and parse the results ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure how Algolia is missing something this basic as an "OR" search when with Elastic search just saying " amazon OR books" gets me the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Algolia settings you are looking for is [`optionalWords`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/swift/parameters/#optionalwords).

When you set this search parameter to your query ("amazon books" in this case), all words will be considered as optional and you will get all the results you want.

Comment: that worked, thanks so much. Wasnt clear from the description in Algolia

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we'll update the documentation accordingly so it's more understandable.